# Multiple javascript selected from dropdown cannot seem to co-exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am building a dynamically created string in which multiple dropdown downs are being looked at for their values etc..

```
HTML:    <div id="codeSnip">WHERE ... </div>
```

Then on a button click a javascript function is called:

```
function applyFilters(val)  {

    var x = document.getElementById("codeSnip");
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 

    //var column = []; 
    //$('[id^=selectNumber] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    //column[i] = $(selected).text(); 

    var conditions = []; 
    $('[id^=condition] :selected').each(function(z, selected){ 
    conditions[z] = $(selected).text();      


    //newContent = document.createTextNode(column[i]);  
    //x.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 
    newContent = document.createTextNode(conditions[z]);  
    x.appendChild(newContent); 

    newContent =  document.createTextNode(" AND ");  
    x.appendChild(newContent); 

});
```

I cannot seem do have BOTH dropdowns to exist without there being an error on my original column creator which really has nothing to do at runtime as alerts and console.log report nothing.

```
Error:   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

- (which is for a different function that dynamically creates the dropdowns) but as soon as I comment out **one** of the 2 dropdowns  named **selectNumber** OR **condition** - then it works.  Not sure why these both cannot be used.

Update:  I did make changes that were suggested but very similar error in the creating function.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Which is this function :

```
function columnCreator(columnArray, selectId) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(selectId);
    for (var i = 0; i < columnArray.length; ++i) {
        // Append the element to the end of Array list
        dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(columnArray[i], columnArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: side note - you can use just jquery for selecting dom elements instead of both jquery and javascript

Comment: side note - jquery is javascript.

Comment: Yes, I was using only jQuery - but with a lot of dynamically created code I was not enjoying jQuery and I was backing off from it getting closer to the metal.  So then I did end up needing a datapicker, so adding in jquery back into the project I started using jQuery again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error exists because your arguments list was never closed:

```
$('[id^=selectNumber] :selected').each(callback);
```

After the callback, the statement needs to be closed. So you will et someting like this:

```
function applyFilters(val)  {

    var x = document.getElementById("codeSnip");
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 

    var column = []; 
    $('[id^=selectNumber] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
        column[i] = $(selected).text(); 

        newContent = document.createTextNode(column[i]);  
        x.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 
    });

    var conditions = []; 
    $('[id^=condition] :selected').each(function(z, selected){ 
        conditions[z] = $(selected).text();

        newContent = document.createTextNode(conditions[z]);  
        x.appendChild(newContent);  
    }); 

    newContent =  document.createTextNode(" AND ");  
    x.appendChild(newContent); 

}
```

Comment: I was hoping that was the problem, but it isn't.

Comment: Working now, I must have been missing a bracket..  Thanks!